# How to distinguish between custom and "built-in" fonts in iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts, info.plist

I have included several Google Fonts ttf files in my iOS project as custom fonts.  Everything works and I can use the fonts fine.  However, I need to distinguish between custom fonts and those automatically provided by iOS.

I have tried comparing filenames returned by UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName with the fonts' filenames in the Info.plist file.  Although it works for most fonts, the filenames don't always match the font names; some may have underscores or dashes in them.  Since I can't rely on the filename to be exact, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a challenge and it isn't straight forward but definitely doable.

What you need is to know which "font name" comes out of the box and which one doesn't.

In order to find that this is how I would do it. Create a dummy brand new sample project. In AppDelegate.m file add this

```
// Get All fonts
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];

for (int i=0; i<[fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Font: %@ ...", [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

This will give you the names of all fonts that are installed by default iOS. You can store that info in a plist file in your doc dir.

Now run the same command in your custom project. It will give you both your iOS & your own custom fonts. Again store that info in a different plist file in your doc dir.

Now what you need to do is get both these plist files in one project, read each of them into an array and compare the arrays. That will give you which fonts you have added and which ones are out of the box.

Comment: I thought about that, but can I rely on that across devices and iOS versions?  Couldn't that list change?

Comment: good question, I would think the list never changes. I mean the fonts that come bundled with iOS 9 are the same whether its iPhone or iPad, Having said that I haven't tried it with an iPad. For sure the list will be different for iOS8 Vs iOS 9